# Why does eclipse always wrap after @param myParameter in JavaDoc?

Tags: eclipse, autoformatting

I have this piece of Java-Code:

```
/**
 * Initializes the Levenshtein Object with the two given words.
 * 
 * @param word1 first word
 * @param word2 second word
 */
public Levenshtein(String word1, String word2) {
    this.word1 = "." + word1.toLowerCase();
    this.word2 = "." + word2.toLowerCase();
    this.distance = new int[this.word2.length()][this.word1
            .length()];
}
```

If I press Ctrl + Shift + F, I get this:

```
/**
 * Initializes the Levenshtein Object with the two given words.
 * 
 * @param word1
 *            first word
 * @param word2
 *            second word
 */
public Levenshtein(String word1, String word2) {
    this.word1 = "." + word1.toLowerCase();
    this.word2 = "." + word2.toLowerCase();
    this.distance = new int[this.word2.length()][this.word1
            .length()];
}
```

Why does eclipse do this pram-line-wrapping? How can I switch it of (without switching it of completely for JavaDoc)?

These are the [Formatter settings](https://github.com/MartinThoma/prog-ws1213/blob/master/Dokumente/Formatter.xml) I currently use in eclipse 3.5.2 (Galileo).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Window > Preferences > Java > Code style > Formatter
(Edit) > Comments
Check box: New line after @param tags

Seen in Juno (4.2).

Comment: Hey, it was annoying me too (although I use Ctrl+F selectively, so I am rarely affected by this), so thanks for the question! :-)

Comment: It's `<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.insert_new_line_for_parameter" value="do not insert"/>` in the XML.